# NVMe SSD disk on AWS Sagemaker Notebook Instances

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Sagemake Studio added support for instances with attached high-performance SSDs. Among others, the M5d instance features an attached SSD. (See, for instance here [AWS Blog: Amazon SageMaker now supports M5d, R5, P3dn, and G4dn instances for SageMaker Notebook Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/08/amazon-sagemaker-supports-m5d-r5-p3dn-g4dn-instances-sagemaker-notebook-instances/))

My question is, how do I make use of the SSD?

The block device is not mounted when I start a Notebook with a Kernel on an M5d instance.
Below is a listing of the mount command form inside the notebook. I can see it when executing `lsblk`. (output is also below). However, there is no way I can format or mount the disk as the environment is restricted by Linux capabilities.

```
!mount

overlay on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/dataroot/data-root/200010.1001/overlay2/l/JGWGMF4ZZ6PHEWK6JM4VICT7E4:/var/lib/dataroot/data-root/200010.1001/overlay2/l/66JWDG6GVXACNLSFJJBEOVZUO4:/var/lib/dataroot/data-root/200010.1001/overlay2/l/3U4YS24OOOKWXXZ7GZ3N4YOJZU:/var/lib/dataroot/data-root/200010.1001/overlay2/l/XOM2F2QYQYJMEUDYRFWJF637G2:/var/lib/dataroot/data-root/200010.1001/overlay2/l/4SSLKXEKJRW2M3MDUY6GRWQZOR:/var/lib/dataroot/data-root/200010.1001/overlay2/l/MDSB4ZKIAUXBZ3U5S4YM4DDOLQ:/var/lib/dataroot/data-root/200010.1001/overlay2/l/NE42TLPPST4P26YJZXL7KQYD5V:/var/lib/dataroot/data-root/200010.1001/overlay2/l/ZQA5ST7XAT673MNTWDL4YWBHLL:/var/lib/dataroot/data-root/200010.1001/overlay2/l/UZYHAWYHUINESI25LGXT5V2RHY:/var/lib/dataroot/data-root/200010.1001/overlay2/l/QECAGRX3FEW5FAJXK5DACNEFKA:/var/lib/dataroot/data-root/200010.1001/overlay2/l/IBZBCWE3M7DNAUXEOAHQUCM5HG:/var/lib/dataroot/data-root/200010.1001/overlay2/l/VQMIS7KW6ZB5VOQNKQE3J2RF4J:/var/lib/dataroot/data-root/200010.1001/overlay2/l/UOWDHH53G2E442U6NNUMBITSRJ,upperdir=/var/lib/dataroot/data-root/200010.1001/overlay2/9b5b78d144189e2437ee3a1716d2215d6a101155c2b35f9e8c0c3b1004b627fd/diff,workdir=/var/lib/dataroot/data-root/200010.1001/overlay2/9b5b78d144189e2437ee3a1716d2215d6a101155c2b35f9e8c0c3b1004b627fd/work)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755,uid=200010,gid=1001)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=10000004,mode=620,ptmxmode=666)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=755,uid=200010,gid=1001)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=65536k,uid=200010,gid=1001)
127.0.0.1:/200010 on /root type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,noresvport,proto=tcp,port=20486,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=127.0.0.1,local_lock=none,addr=127.0.0.1)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /opt/.sagemakerinternal type xfs (rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,usrquota,prjquota)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /etc/resolv.conf type xfs (rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,usrquota,prjquota)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /etc/hostname type xfs (rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,usrquota,prjquota)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /etc/hosts type xfs (rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,usrquota,prjquota)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /var/log/studio type xfs (rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,usrquota,prjquota)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /var/log/apps type xfs (rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,usrquota,prjquota)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /opt/ml/metadata/resource-metadata.json type xfs (ro,noatime,attr2,inode64,usrquota,prjquota)
devtmpfs on /dev/null type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=16042360k,nr_inodes=4010590,mode=755)
devtmpfs on /dev/random type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=16042360k,nr_inodes=4010590,mode=755)
devtmpfs on /dev/full type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=16042360k,nr_inodes=4010590,mode=755)
devtmpfs on /dev/tty type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=16042360k,nr_inodes=4010590,mode=755)
devtmpfs on /dev/zero type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=16042360k,nr_inodes=4010590,mode=755)
devtmpfs on /dev/urandom type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=16042360k,nr_inodes=4010590,mode=755)
proc on /proc/bus type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc/fs type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc/irq type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc/sys type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc/sysrq-trigger type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /proc/acpi type tmpfs (ro,relatime,uid=200010,gid=1001)
devtmpfs on /proc/kcore type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=16042360k,nr_inodes=4010590,mode=755)
devtmpfs on /proc/keys type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=16042360k,nr_inodes=4010590,mode=755)
devtmpfs on /proc/latency_stats type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=16042360k,nr_inodes=4010590,mode=755)
devtmpfs on /proc/timer_list type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=16042360k,nr_inodes=4010590,mode=755)
devtmpfs on /proc/sched_debug type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=16042360k,nr_inodes=4010590,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/firmware type tmpfs (ro,relatime,uid=200010,gid=1001)
```

```
!lsblk

NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme1n1       259:0    0 279.4G  0 disk 
nvme0n1       259:1    0   124G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1   259:2    0   124G  0 part /opt/ml/metadata/resource-metadata.json
└─nvme0n1p128 259:3    0     1M  0 part
```

Comment: I contacted AWS support and apparently it does not work. Just in case anyone else is trying this.